# How to extend the Android settings menu?

Tags: android, menu, settings

I want to extend the existing settings menu with one point (I want to add the option "infinite" to Settings -> Display -> Screen timeout). Does anybody know where I can find the sources for doing this? I think somewhere in frameworks/base/... ?
Thank you!

Comment: You will find that StackOverflow is better for supporting SDK applications than for firmware modifications. I strongly encourage you to indicate in your questions that you are modifying the firmware, so we do not assume that you are creating an app with the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: you can't, because the Settings app does not provide this option. You would have to write your own Settings app.

If it's of any use, you can find the sources to the Settings app here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings

Comment: I don't really understand. The settings menu belongs to the operating system which is open source. Somewhere it has to be possible to edit the sources and build the system again. Or do I think wrong?

Comment: Ah I think I just find by myself: android-2.3.3_r1\packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\DisplaySettings.java line 193

Comment: Yes, you can. Sorry, I assumed you wanted to build a simple app that added that option. Of course you can modify the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a WakeLock is a decent alternative approach.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html